# Equivalent Definition of Independence

Tags: probability

Let's restrict ourselves to continuous random variables.  The usual definition says that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if:
$$F(a, b) = P(X \le a, Y \le b) = P(X \le a)P(Y \le b) = F_X(a)F_Y(b)$$
I already confirmed that the condition $f_{XY} = f_Xf_Y$ implies that $F = F_XF_Y$.  Is the other direction also true?

$$\begin{align}
F(a, b) = \int^{b}_{-\infty} \int^{a}_{-\infty} f_{XY}(x, y) \, dxdy \ \ & = \ \ 
\int^{b}_{-\infty} \int^{a}_{-\infty} f_X(x)f_Y(y) \, dxdy = F_X(a)F_X(b) \\
f_{XY}(a, b) \ \ & \stackrel{?}{=} \ \ f_X(a)f_Y(b)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Apply $\partial_a\partial_b$ to both sides, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

As @eyeballfrog suggested:

1. The usual definition of independence says that *for all $a,b$* : $$\mathsf P(X\leqslant a,Y\leqslant b)=\mathsf P(X\leqslant a)\,\mathsf P(Y\leqslant b)$$
2. If $X$ and $Y$ do have probability density functions, then they are, by definition:

$$\begin{align}f_{X,Y}(a,b) &= \dfrac{\mathrm d^2\mathsf P(X\leqslant a,Y\leqslant b)}{\mathrm d a~\mathrm d b}\\[1ex]f_{X}(a) &= \dfrac{\mathrm d\mathsf P(X\leqslant a)}{\mathrm d a}\\[1ex]f_{Y}(b) &= \dfrac{\mathrm d\mathsf P(Y\leqslant b)}{\mathrm d b}\end{align}$$

Put it together .